# Is there a way to set a default separatorin exporting a phpMyadmin database to csv?

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I need to export several of my tables to Excel, which I can do via the export > CSV for MS Excel function. But the file created uses a semicolon ';' as the field separator...but Excel needs a comma ','.

Is there a way to change/set the default to the comma?

Comment: if you're using msyql to export, then this site ( https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-export-a-csv-file-from-mysql-command-line/) will help and in excel the field separator is configurable in the import dialog box.

Comment: OK,that's a way to code it - I'm asking if there is a setting in the phpMyAdmin DB to do this, so I don't need to run the php every time. the csv for Excel needs the comma,so why is it set to semicolon?

Comment: I guess the real question is rhetorical:  if it can't be done, why not?

Comment: the semicolon column separator surprised me to, if I'm not mistaken phpMyAdmin DB is open source and depending on your background and motivation, can be modify to use comma. Or just write a small bash script to replace ';' with ',' (e.g>  file | bashscript > CSV file).

Comment: this site claims phpMyAdmin can be configure to export CSV file,  https://hevodata.com/learn/mysql-export-to-csv/#php,  shows step-by-step instructions.

Comment: MZM, thanks for the response - it appears that using the CSV format,instead of the CSV for Excel uses the comma instead of the semicolon! Seems a bit backwards, but it works!